# NDSolve: problem due to boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a 2nd order ordinary linear differential equation (`DE==0`). Here is the code:

```
g[z_] := 1 + 3 (z/z0)^4 - 4 (z/z0)^3

DE = x''[z] + D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) x'[z] +  (w^2)/(g[z])^2 x[z] == 0;

pfun = Block[{z0 = 0.1, ep = 10^-2, zb = 10^-2},
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{DE, x'[z0 - ep] == I (z0^2 w)/(6 ep^2)  x[z0 - ep], 
    x[zb] == 1}, - x'[zb], {z, zb, z0 - ep}, {w}]
];

Plot[{Re[pfun[w]], Im[pfun[w]]}, {w, -0.1, 0.1}]
```

Actually, I am supposed to put the boundary conditions at `z=z0` and `z=0` i.e. I need to take `ep` and `zb` to `0`. But for smaller values of `ep` and `zb` some numerical errors creep in (on the plot for  `ep` and `zb` of the order `10^-4`). Can someone suggest me how to improve the result?

Comment: Can you show a concrete example for the numerical errors? Have you tried a higher `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: @xzczd I have added two more lines in my question to clarify. N
No, I didn't know about `WorkingPrecision` . I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried `ep=zb=10^-4`, though some warning pops up, the "shape" of result looks quite similar to that with `ep=zb=10^-2`, what's the unexpected part?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aw0xw.png

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have an analytic expression for `- x'[z b]` (valid for small `w`) which has one free parameter (up to an overall number). If I fit that parameter with these numerical plots that parameter fluctuates rapidly with the b.c